# Netsuite Rest API returns "No Content" status (204) when completed successfully

Tags: python, python-requests, netsuite

i use the requests library. how can this be the default behavior? any way to return the ID of the item created?

```
def create_sales_order():
    url = f"https://{url_account}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder"

    data = {
        "entity": {
            "id": "000"
        },
        "item": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "id": 25
                    },
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "amount": 120
                }
            ]
        },
        "memo": "give me money",
        "Department": "109"
    }

    body = json.dumps(data)

    response = client.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that the header returned in the 204 empty response contains a link to the created item (Location is the key name in the json returned) , which is sufficient to do another get request and have all the info returned.

Comment: I was just about to start crying with such a poor design of their API, but you, sir, have saved me from going crazy

Comment: This is still just an awful design. There's no indication from what I can find that says it does this. It's proper to return a 201 Created with a json body. Either way, thank you for finding it. Saved me a lot of time getting hacky. I don't I would have found it.